# How to map out an 80x80 world given local 5x5 arrays around the agent after each move?

Tags: c, arrays, maps, artificial-intelligence, agent

Specifications:

- An agent is in a (maximum) 80x80 2D text-based world. It can move
  Forward, pivot left 90 degrees, or pivot right 90 degree on every
  turn.
- After each turn, the game client provides the agent with a 5x5 array
  of the world immediately surrounding the agent (with the agent in the
  middle at index [2][2]).
- The agent is always facing North relative to the provided 5x5 array,
  so if he does a pivot, the whole 5x5 array will have the same
  elements in it but will be rotated 90 degrees in the appropriate
  direction.

I am trying to construct a global map array via these 5x5 snippets of the world, but am not sure how to go about this. I can easily determine my relative direction (N, S, E, W) via a function I've coded, so that isn't an issue.

My best idea so far is to keep four 80x80 arrays, one for each N, S, E, W. When moving forward in a particular direction I will add a row to the top of the appropriately directed array with the new information that was received about the world, and appropriately convert this to the remaining 3 arrays. The main issue here is how to behave when retreading on an area that has already been explored, and what happens if the number of columns and rows in the array are not the same so there are small gaps in corners of un-explored areas, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Obviously, you don't rotate the entire world to keep the agent facing north, but redefine which way the agent's "north" is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the world is always this small, and you nothing about the terrain, I'd just make an array that's big enough to handle you possibly being in any starting position, 159x159.  Start your character dead in the middle (at 80, 80), and assume he's starting in an orientation where forward means moving up to 79, 80.  Track the location as cell coordinates and map each action to a new location when any move is made (actually moving or just rotating).